# Тире или двоеточие при описании города

Tags: бсп, тире-или-двоеточие

***Зумадор встретил путников вечерними огнями – уютно светились окна высотных домов, желто сияли дорожные фонари, весело перемигивались светофоры на перекрестках.** Разноцветные витрины магазинов выглядели как волшебные пещеры, отгороженные от остального мира толстыми стеклами, там и тут по фасаду зданий пробегала огненная реклама, призывающая немедленно купить то-то и то-то, пусть и ненужное, но – купить! И чем больше, тем лучше* (М. Бабкин, 2005).

Почему здесь поставлено **тире** (по какому правилу и с каким значением)? Можно ли его заменить двоеточием и обосновать свой выбор?

Спасибо.

Comment: А вы специально спрашиваете провокационно? Спрашиваете так, будто вы за двоеточие, а оказывается наоборот. Почти что каждый раз так. Я не стану отвечать, защищая, как адвокат, чьё-то стремление, желание — отвечаю честно.

Comment: Тире или двоеточие —  вот в чем вопрос . Откроем живописную мастерскую, ага?  А то у вас как-то  ученье туго продвигается :)))  Попробуйте вот что запомнить.  Если ДВОЕТОЧИЕ, то это  подчеркнутая остановка и понижение тона (неполное!!)  – называется «сейчас я тебе такое расскажу!».  А если тире, то примерно так:   «короче, тут столько огней, фонари, перекрестки, ну  и всё такое.  А в городе  так вообще красота – будто пещеры с камнями-самоцветами  светятся! И  вот это уже ГЛАВНЫЙ ПЛАН, центр композиции. На нем нужно внимание сосредоточить.

Comment: Теперь понятно, почем нельзя было двоеточие в начале фрагмента ставить и там останавливаться, а только тире?  Главное-то было  впереди! (Нам бы еще художника какого раздобыть, чтобы терминологию поправлял. ) Ну на первый раз хватит… :))

Comment: Мне не кажется, что "постановка двоеточия заканчивает описание". Оно же расширяется. Вы раньше говорили о распространении мысли. Соответственно, про главный план тоже не кажется. После двоеточия более конкретно о чём-то говорится. Почему это не может быть "главным планом"? Причина того, что двоеточие не подходит, в том, что мы не можем понизить интонацию на "вечерними огнями" (с уверенностью, что всё в порядке — при непорядке интонация не понижается) из-за неясности этого сочетания. Будь там что-то другое и понятное (а подобрать что-то такое у меня не получается), двоеточие бы подошло.

Comment: Нет, всё-таки получилось, но не про огни. *Зумадор встретил путников яркою красотою: уютно светились окна высотных домов, желто сияли дорожные фонари, весело перемигивались светофоры на перекрестках.*

Comment: Вы не художник. Я, конечно, тоже, но зато поклонник и любитель, да еще книг по композиции в свое время начиталась достаточно.  И очень хорошо усвоила, что размазывать краски по всему полотну нельзя, должен быть четкий центр. А вы размазываете. Первые огни - это как бы вступление к основному  зрелищу, вы туда должны устремить внимание читателя.

Comment: *да еще книг по композиции в свое время начиталась достаточно* — сочинять что-то по формулам — это искусственность, в этом нет творчества, это как математика. Нужно чувствовать (как можно и как нельзя и как надо) и практиковаться в этом. Давайте лучше про мой вариант, там понижение голоса уже подходит, как и двоеточие (и оно выигрывает из-за перечисления).

Comment: Какой-то вы дерзкий "ученик", а я смирных больше люблю. Ваш вариант вполне себе хорош, если дальше перейти к повествованию, а описание на этом закончить. oleedd, а как повысить количество просмотров для вопроса (чтобы набрать потенциальных слушателей курса :)). Может быть,  изменить название –  "Тире и двоеточие при описании пейзажа"?  Или еще что? Вы знаете какие-нибудь технологии для раскрутки ресурсов в Сети вообще?

Comment: Эту тему я знаю хорошо, мне тут учиться точно не надо. Это же не пейзаж, пейзаж — это про природу. Начнём с того, что все вопросы просматривают постоянные участники (думаю, что они его уже видели), а новые интересуются лишь ответом на свой вопрос. Технологии — публикация ссылки в соцсетях (в частности, у себя на странице), на других сайтах, в роликах на Youtube (если вы блогер), использование тегов (не для этого сайта). На этом сайте — публикация вопросов общего характера, вопросов о том, что было бы полезно либо интересно многим, вопросов, которые люди могли бы загуглить (для поиска информ.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь после тире поясняется одно слово, можно вставить "это" (тире ставится, если можно подставить это слово, то есть обратный принцип, а не только тогда, когда это слово есть):
*Зумадор встретил путников вечерними огнями – **это** уютно светились окна высотных домов, желто сияли дорожные фонари, весело перемигивались светофоры на перекрестках.*

У двоеточия пояснение широкое, не такое целенаправленное, как у тире.

Вы же не напишете так:
*Вечерние огни: уютно светящиеся окна высотных домов.*
Так и в конце предложения не следует так делать.

Но здесь есть перечисление — хороший повод для двоеточия. Но для него необходимо, чтобы было понятно, что именно перечисляется, а здесь это непонятно, потому что это образно, художественно, настоящим огнём (факелами) встречают вампиров. Так что пояснительная задача выносится на первый план.

Comment: Вот этот принцип у Розенталя: Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова *именно, а именно, то есть* (**при их отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены**).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  А вот без манипуляций никак нельзя (переставить, подставить, в значении), это же школьные приемы. Думаете, писатели так  пишут? Они, как я думаю,  интуитивно знают, какой знак поставить. А вы могли бы так научиться?  Здесь, вероятно, весь контекст надо учитывать. Постановка двоеточия как бы заканчивает описание, а оно ведь продолжается дальше,  вся картина еще не прорисована.

Comment: Школьные приёмы, но универсальные. *А вы могли бы так научиться?* — а я умею, но здесь же надо объяснять знаки.

Comment: Точно всё умеете? И тире бы поставили в первом предложении, а не двоеточие?  Класс! Ну, тогда будем считать, что тема различения двоеточия и тире  на нашем форуме  изучена, успешно освоена, интереса не вызывает, так что обсуждать ее больше не будем.

Comment: Никто не умеет всё. Поставил бы тире, а двоеточие вообще не хочу (причина в последнем абзаце). Сейчас ещё кое-что заметил: при перечислении были бы существительные, без глаголов (*светящимися окнами высотных домов, дорожными фонарями, светофорами на перекрёстках*), — тогда двоеточие в тему. *так что обсуждать ее больше не будем* — как говорится, никогда не говори никогда, может попасться что-то очень спорное.

Comment: Да я не против, обсуждайте, пожалуйста.... Просто я эту тему вижу и понимаю иначе, как бы  воспринимаю ее НА СЛУХ.   В устной речи мы строим фразы ПО ИНТУИЦИИ, вот что ценно.  Ни о чем не задумываемся – и говорим красиво, правильно, выразительно.  И ударения ставим, где надо. Но начинаем писать   – и куда что девается!  Значит, надо «слышать» знаки – вот это истинное умение и понимание русской пунктуации, как я думаю.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в устной речи мы вообще не думаем о знаках, а умение "слышать" выработается, если думать.

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться с вами. Мы знаем фонетическую характеристику каждого знака и знаем его звуковые возможности.  Поэтому это вполне управляемый и осознанный выбор. Как музыку записывают нотами, так  и устную речь можно записать знаками препинания. К примеру, в том предложении  удлиненная пауза (двоеточие) совершенно не у места, вот мы и не ставим двоеточие.

Comment: Длина паузы — это самый маловажный критерий, никогда по нему не ориентировался. Длина паузы — это просто тенденция, оно не является обязательным. Самый важный критерий — смысловая связь между фрагментами (следствие, причина, перечисление, вывод, подчёркивание, определение понятия, добавление информации, уточнение).

Comment: Эта пауза особенная, она называется интонационное предупреждение (у Розенталя): неполное понижение тона перед значительно увеличенной паузой. Два критерия: длина паузы и движение  тона - этого достаточно, чтобы уловить на слух.    Мне нужно коротко пересказать вам всю теорию, иначе нет смысла говорить.  Перешлю вам по облаку, захотите, так прочитаете.

Comment: Понижение тона — абсолютно, а вот длину паузы могут проигнорировать в устной речи.